# How do I invite a friend in The Expendabros?

Tags: the-expendabros

The question is clear, how do I invite a player or friend to the game on steam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this game only support local Co-Op, you cannot invite a player into your game session. Local Co-Op means you can only play it with others in front of your computer.

Comment: Wow... that's so lame :/